# Separating a data frame into appropriate columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have extracted data from a pdf and now have a dataframe (my_data) of 3085 observations (characters) of 1 variable (stuff), here are two rows:

```
2012 Q-2 1004001115648091 001 2011-12-02 10 000,00 $ 2 500,00 $ 10,00 $ 495,65 $ 13 005,65 $

2012 Q-2 r.19 1004001113343232 001 2009-11-05 50 000,00 $ 2 900,00 $ 10,00 $ 52 910,00 $
```

How do I separate this into 11 variables, as it was originally in the pdf, and fill the blanks with NAs? Good separation would look like this:

```
2012 / Q-2 / NA / 1004001115648091 / 001 / 2011-12-02 / 10 000,00 $ / 2 500,00 $ / 10,00 $ / 495,65 $ / 13 005,65 $

2012 / Q-2 / r.19 / 1004001113343232 / 001 / 2009-11-05 / 50 000,00 $ / 2 900,00 $ / 10,00 $ / 52 910,00 $
```

I am trying to find a way to do it with separate(), but I don't have a good grasp of regular expressions and the best I could achieve so far, based on an online blog, was this:

```
my_data %>% 
  separate(stuff, c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L"), sep = "\\s")
```

Which creates a separation at every white space. This is problematic as it separates $ from amounts and 1 000 into two different columns, and it does not fill the blank with NAs when there are missing values, instead shifting the whole thing to fill the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.
However, as it is ever the case with regexps out of small samples, i'm not sure if it covers all cases.

```r
data = c(
"2012 Q-2 1004001115648091 001 2011-12-02 10 000,00 $ 2 500,00 $ 10,00 $ 495,65 $ 13 005,65 $",
"2012 Q-2 r.19 1004001113343232 001 2009-11-05 50 000,00 $ 2 900,00 $ 10,00 $ 52 910,00 $")

r <- regexec(paste0(
"(\\d{4}) (Q-\\d) (?:([^ ]+) )?(\\d{16}) (\\d{3}) (\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}) ",
"(-?\\d{1,3}(?: \\d{3})*,\\d{2} \\$) (-?\\d{1,3}(?: \\d{3})*,\\d{2} \\$) ",
"(-?\\d{1,3}(?: \\d{3})*,\\d{2} \\$)"), data) 

do.call(rbind, regmatches(data, r))[,-1]
#>      [,1]   [,2]  [,3]   [,4]               [,5]  [,6]         [,7]         
#> [1,] "2012" "Q-2" ""     "1004001115648091" "001" "2011-12-02" "10 000,00 $"
#> [2,] "2012" "Q-2" "r.19" "1004001113343232" "001" "2009-11-05" "50 000,00 $"
#>      [,8]         [,9]     
#> [1,] "2 500,00 $" "10,00 $"
#> [2,] "2 900,00 $" "10,00 $"
```